# Principios SOLID dentro do Controller do Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mvc, solid

Dentro dos principios SOLID, como implementar os 2 primeiros principios ?

SRP e Open-Closed Principle.

A minha estrutura é simples, tem models dentro do app gerados pelo artisan, e controllers simples. Um exemplo de um método que eu gostaria de refatorar é esse que eu vou passar abaixo..

Eu não acho nenhum lugar no Laravel aonde posso colocar as classes, tem algum lugar padrão ?

Ele recebe uma requisição Http via ajax e renderiza o resultado na view..

Como exemplo eu vou passar uma funcao privada , que simplesmente faz requisicoes diferentes dependendo do status pesquisado, eu criei uma função especial pra ela, para não ter que ficar repetindo varias vezes durante o codigo

```
private function recarregarAjaxPedidos($statusPesquisado,$codEmpresa)
    {
        $pedidos = [];
        if($statusPesquisado == "T")
        {
            $pedido = DB:table /* resto da query */ ->get()

        } else  if($statusPesquisado == "T") {
            $pedido = DB:table /* resto da query */ ->get()
        } else  if($statusPesquisado == "PR") {
            $pedido = DB:table /* resto da query */ ->get()
        } else {
            $pedido = DB:table /* resto da query */ ->get()
        }

        return $pedido;

    }
```

Comment: Não é melhor manter a simplicidade e eficiência ??? Tipo ai você pode trabalhar nesse método privado com `Builder`?

Comment: Melhor nem tentar fazer isso. Estude profundamente o assunto, ou pelo menos o básico antes de fazer isso. Qual o objetivo de complicar algo que você nem entende ainda? Faça o simples, quando tiver necessidade de fazer algo mais, aí você faz, enquanto isso estudo o assunto. Sua pergunta mostra que nem entende o que SOLID ou esses princípios, leu em algum lugar que ele é legal (e não é bem assim, ele tem problemas) e quer usar de qualquer jeito, mais ou menos assim: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofbhu.jpg. Tem alguma dúvida específica?

Comment: É igual no Laravel o pessoal complica ta tudo pronto é só usar ... eu também acho que deve ser usar se sabe e também se precisa.

Comment: A pergunta que te faço é *"qual a vantagem você enxerga nisto?"*, não tem necessidade nenhuma, eu escultei tanta gente falando de solid como se fosse solução mágica para problemas, mas a maioria são pessoas que usam porque optam ou porque não entendem e outra pessoa disse *"isso é o mais moderno"*. Resumindo, pergunte a si mesmo, qual a vantagem que terei sobre isto e se houver vantagem o caminho seria entender como funciona. Vou ser sincero, o uso de frameworks na maioria das vezes um exagero. A maioria dos FWs tem péssima performance e geralmente vc não usa nem 10% das funcionalidades.

Comment: Da para fazer isso que eu me lembre com Switch

Comment: @Maniero acho que se ele rever as boas práticas já resolve a treta

Comment: É claro que eu não vou modificar o projeto que estou mexendo, mas penso em um modo de mexer nele usando solid, iria criar uma classe para cada if estendendo de uma classe abstrata do tipo RenderizarResultadosAbstract.

Uma outra questão, aonde são colocadas por padrão as classes no Laravel, no mesmo lugar que o model ?

Answer (score -1):

Uma forma que você pode estar usando que ajudaria até na performance do seu sistema.

```
private function recarregarAjaxPedidos($statusPesquisado,$codEmpresa)
    {
        $pedidos = [];

        switch($statusPesquisado){
            case("T"):
             $pedido = DB:table /* resto da query */ ->get();
             break;
            case("PR"):
             $pedido = DB:table /* resto da query */ ->get();
             break;
            default:
              $pedido = DB:table /* resto da query */ ->get();
        }

        return $pedido;

    }
```